# Como mover elementos em HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Já dei uma procurada na internet de como fazer mas nenhum está dando certo.

Criei uma `class` chamada `.img` para testar e na hora de tratá-la no CSS, uso `.img{right: 500px;}` como teste, porém nada acontece.

Minha ideia era colocar o bloco de imagens (todas `100px` por `100 px`) começando nos 30% da página, e não centralizada (o que eu diria como 50%).

**Obs.:** Como fiz uma página apenas para uso no meu PC, não coloquei muita frescura, apenas gostaria de fazer uma página de favoritos agradável e útil para mim. Não programo em HTML, apenas quis fazer uma página assim, e por curiosidade fiz isso para atender a necessidade.

Como está a página -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/brDou.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/83qzZ.jpg

Imagem superior -> Como está com `div` dentro de `<center>`

Imagem inferior -> Como gostaria que ficasse

Código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>:: Home Page ::</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css" media="all" />
    </head>
    <body background="images/fundo.jpg" bgproperties="fixed">

        <!--<center>-->
            <div>
                <p><img class="img" src="images/bookmarks.png" alt="Bookmarks" /></a></p>
                <p>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/fb.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
                    <a href="https://forum.pokexgames.com/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/pxg.jpg" alt="PXG Fórum" /></a>
                    <a href="http://youtube.com/feed/subscriptions" target="_blank" ><img src="images/youtube.jpg" alt="YouTube" /></a>
                    <a href="https://jovemnerd.com.br/nerdcast/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/jn.jpg" alt="Nerdcast" /></a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/github.png" alt="GitHub" /></a>
                    <a href="https://codefights.com/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/codefights.png" alt="Codefights" /></a>
                    <a href="https://www.datacamp.com/home" target="_blank" ><img src="images/datacamp.png" alt="Datacamp" /></a>
                    <a href="http://reborn.farma-alg.com.br/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/farmaalg.jpg" alt="FarmaAlg" /></a>

                </p>
                <p>

                    <a href="https://www.codecademy.com" target="_blank" ><img src="images/codecademy.jpg" alt="Codecademy" /></a>
                    <a href="https://pt.khanacademy.org/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/khan.jpg" alt="Khan Academy" /></a>
                    <a href="https://trello.com/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/trello.png" alt="Trello" /></a>
                    <a href="https://www.sololearn.com/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/sololearn.jpg" alt="SoloLearn" /></a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/wpp.png" alt="Whatsapp" /></a>
                    <a href="https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/urionline.gif" alt="URI Judge" /></a>
                    <a href="https://br.pinterest.com/" target="_blank" ><img src="images/pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" /></a>
                    <a href="https://webmail.inf.ufpr.br/?_task=mail&_mbox=INBOX" target="_blank" ><img src="images/roundcube.png" alt="Roundcube" /></a>
                </p>
            <div>
        <!--</center>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Código CSS:

```
.img {right: 500px}
```

Comment: `right: 500px;` é para posicionar a 500 pixeis da direita. É isso que pretende fazer ? No entanto só funciona para posicionamento relativo ou absoluto. Ou está a tentar atribuir o tamanho das imagens ? Não consegui perceber o que está a tentar fazer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NHhHu
Veja nesta imagem. O quadrado de dentro seria a grade 4x4 de imagens(100px por 100px cada). Na imagem de cima é como a grade fica usando <center>.
E a de baixo é com oeu gostaria que ficasse, porém usando estes códigos ela não se mexe. Mesmo que eu tire o <center> fica tudo na esquerda apenas, sem mover nem um px.

Comment: Tente colocando `position: relative;` na classe `.img`

Comment: Alem disso, tem um `</a>` sobrando depois da imagem.

Comment: Faltava o position: relative mesmo. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa amigo!

Não deu pra entender diretamente o que você quer fazer mas vamos as ideias...

Na sua tentativa de mover 500px a direita, para que funcione pode utilizar alguns metodos:

```
.img{right: 500px; float:left;}
```

Ou também:

```
.img{right: 500px; position:absolute;}
```

Porém, se quer que comece a partir dos 30% da página, teria que mudar os 500px por 30%.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa pergunte!

Comment: Tentei os dois agora e nenhum moveu.
https://imgur.com/a/NHhHu Neste link tem a primeira imagem(como está) e a segunda (como gostaria que ficasse).

Comment: Você quer mover o que exatamente, somente a imagem?

Comment: Tenho 16 imagens (4x4) com 100px por 100 px cada. Forma um bloco, que ou ficam tudo na esquerda, ou ficam centralizadas usando <center>.
Gostaria que esta grade de imagens fossem posicionadas em 30% da página por exemplo.

Comment: Você poderia desenhar mais ou menos como quer estas 16 imagens? (uma em baixo da outra, etc)

Comment: Atualizei o post com dois links de imagens. Um mostra como está. O outro mostra a ideia de como está, e como gostaria que ficasse.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi então, você quer centralizar toda sua página? Ou fazer com que todo conteudo fique a 30% da esquerda para a direita?

Comment: Não, ela já está centralizada usando o <center>. Gostaria de deixar esta grade de imagens do meio pra esquerda. Mas usando left: 500px ou right: 500px não se mexe. Nem top, nem down, nem nada.
Provavelmente tem algo de errado no codigo pq se eu usar background na class .img, o bg muda.

Comment: Faz assim, naquela <div> antes de <p><img class="img" src="fundo.png" alt="Bookmarks" /></a></p>, cria um estilo pra ela com a "width" no tamanho total das imagens contando com os espaços entre elas, e essa div você poem o left:500px; e o float:left; e me diz se é isso

Comment: Ela tem 400 de largura por ser 4 imagens de 100px, acrescenta o espaço entre elas e põem na width

Comment: Coloquei assim e funcionou: 
.test{left: 20%; float:left; position: absolute;}
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se você for usar position não faz sentido usar o float, ela anula a função float. Feliz por ter ajudado!

Comment: Verdade, tirei aqui e ficou até melhor hehe